# Ratingbar in android

Tags: android, rating

I am using Ratingbar in my android app.Size of filled star is bigger than empty stars as shown here
[image]

I am using this code in layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBarValue"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:progressTint="@color/appBaseColor"
            android:rating="3" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its the drwable image issue ..not the progamming issue..make sure the both images of the same size

Comment: i am not using drawables, as clearly shown top rating bar stars are equal with same code

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:max="5"
            android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@mipmap/apptheme_btn_rating_star_off_focused_holo_light"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step-1. You need your own rating stars in res/drawable ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Step-2 In res/drawable you need myratingstars.xml as follow ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_half_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</layer-list>
```

Step-3 In res/values you need styles.xml as follow ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/myratingstars</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">22dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">22dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Step-4 In your layout ...

```
<RatingBar 
      android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:rating="3.5"
      android:isIndicator="false"
      style="@style/MyCustomRatingBar"    
/>
```